# Update object to another using Panache JPA

Tags: jpa, sql-update, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm working with PanacheRepositories in Quarkus.
Currently I want to realize the function `update(X x)`.
Basically what I want is the function to do is check if an entity `y` exists having `id==x.id` exists and update it to `x`, however I can't figure out if this is possible without having to deep copy every attribute from `x` into `y`.
I don't want that, because the object is huge.

Is there any way to do something like

```
MyEntity y = repository.findById(x.id);
if(y != null){
  y = x;
  repository.persist(y)
}
```

without detaching the entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize that `PanacheRepository` is just an overlay of `EntityManager`, which has the functionality I'm looking for.
So I could just inject the `EntityManager` and use `merge(x)` which did exactly what I wanted